# error /usr/include/string.h:652:42: error: ‘memcpy’ was not declared in this scope while building caffe

Tags: c++, compilation, compiler-errors, makefile, cuda

I'm trying to compile caffe following this guide: https://gist.github.com/wangruohui/679b05fcd1466bb0937f

However when I get too `make all` I get the error

```
NVCC src/caffe/layers/hdf5_data_layer.cu
/usr/include/string.h: In function ‘void* __mempcpy_inline(void*, const void*, size_t)’:
/usr/include/string.h:652:42: error: ‘memcpy’ was not declared in this scope
   return (char *) memcpy (__dest, __src, __n) + __n;
                                          ^
Makefile:585: recipe for target '.build_release/cuda/src/caffe/layers/hdf5_data_layer.o' failed
```

But /usr/include/string.h isn't even in the caffe code so what gives? This is in an ubuntu variant that closely follows 16.04

Seeing as the source of the code is a well known repo I think the problem is probably in the Makefile or the Makefile.config

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a long time looking through various internet sources I solved this problem by going to the Makefile and changing the line

```
NVCCFLAGS += -ccbin=$(CXX) -Xcompiler -fPIC $(COMMON_FLAGS)
```

into

```
NVCCFLAGS += -D_FORCE_INLINES -ccbin=$(CXX) -Xcompiler -fPIC $(COMMON_FLAGS)
```

For me this was on line `406`

Comment: is this the Makefile generated by cmake?  seems to be different